# C#. Reconstruct chunks, received as content of an HTTP request, in a zip archive

Tags: c#, zip, restsharp

Let's suppose having a web site, from which i can download .xml files compressed in .zip archives, and i want to write a code snippet that executes the download of these archives. I precise that this web site doesn't provide any APIs (RESTful or not), so i tried to emulate the behavior of a user that physically clicks on the download button. I'm using RestSharp and the first part of the request is something like this:

```
RestRequest postDownloadRequest = new RestRequest(Settings.DownloadUrl, Method.Post);
postDownloadRequest.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", downloadBodyContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, ParameterType.RequestBody);
Task<RestResponse> postDownloadResponseTask = client.ExecuteAsync(postDownloadRequest);
postDownloadResponseTask.Wait();
```

This code is correct and the request returns 200.

Since `postDownloadResponseTask.Result.Content` contains a long string and the `Transfer-Encoding` header of the response contains the value `chanked`, i suppose that this is the bytes array of the chunked downloaded archive, converted to string. **Is this correct?**

Now i want to rebuild the initial zip archive and to save it in my local machine.
I tried to convert the string in byte[] and than in a stream, and to build a ZipArchive by passing the stream, but it didn't work. **How can i do this as correct as possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by:

```cs
byte[] zipBytes = postDownloadResponseTask.Result.RawBytes;
string path = @"C:\path\your-file-name.zip";
File.WriteAllBytes(path, zipBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#downloading-binary-data)? You don't suppose to use the `Content` property of type `string` for downloading binary data. That's what `DownloadDataAsync` and `DownloadStreamAsync` are for.

Please also note that using `Wait` and `Result` instead of awaiting asynchronous calls will inevitably break your application when it comes under any substantial load. RestSharp has sync overloads for almost everything if you really cannot use async.